# How to resolve promise to variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I get the value out of Promise?

```
let id = getUserID(email, args, context)
        .then(id => id);
```

I'm using `then` but still Promise not resolved.

Comment: You can only get the value in the `then` callback. Promises don't make your code synchronous.

Comment: I didn't get it @FelixKling - could you please share any link.

Comment: See the first duplicate. But basically: `.then(id => <this is where you can access id and nowhere else>)`. I suggest to put all the code that needs to access `id` into a function that accepts `id` as an argument and do `.then(thatFunction)`.

Comment: If you are familiar with using `async`/`await`, you can do this in an `async` function: `let id = await getUserId(email, args, context);`